# Obtener los checkboxes ckekeados cada vez que marque o desmarque uno

Tags: javascript, jquery

No puedo obtener los checkbox marcados (uno de los checkbox está marcado desde su creación), ¿cuál es mi error?

```js
                            
function activar(){
   var yourArray=[];
   $("input:checkbox[name=vehicle]:checked").each(function(){
        yourArray.push($(this).val());
   });
   console.log(yourArray);
}                  

activar();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
```

Intento que me diga, cada vez que marque o desmarque uno de los checkbox, cuáles son los checkbox que están marcados.

Comment: Te está saliendo bien la respuesta. ¿Cuál es tu duda?

Comment: Diría que el error es no volver a ejecutar `activar();` tras _"checkear"_ el otro `checkbox`

Comment: @Error404 crear dinamicamente los checkbox y luego ejecutar la funcion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no he entendido mal lo que quieres realizar es que te diga cada vez que marques o desmarques uno de los checkbox los checkbox que están marcados.

Para ello, puedes añadir la función `onclick` a cada uno de los `checkbox` y de esta manera cada vez que hagas un click sobre ellos para marcarlos/desmarcarlos aparecerá la respuesta en ese mismo momento.

```js
function activar(){
  var yourArray=[];
  $("input:checkbox[name=vehicle]:checked").each(function(){
     yourArray.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(yourArray);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" onclick="activar()"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked onclick="activar()"> I have a car<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si mal no entiendo, quieres que ningún checkbox este checkeado ?
bastaría con quitar el checked del input

```html
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
```

Ademas cuando capturas los checked con el nombre, tienes que poner el atributo id y su nombre tiene que ser diferente en cada uno

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id_bike" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input id="id_car" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
```

Usar esta linea, traerá el checkbox checkeado

> var vehiculo =$('input[name=vehiculo]:checked').val();